# How to get the Angular version?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I installed the `@angular/cli` package via npm using:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

The version 1.4.2 of `@angular/cli` has been successfully installed. That is not the Angular version, but the CLI version.

After running `ng new myapp` how can I check which Angular version the created app is using? 2.x, 4.x?

Answer (score 298, accepted):

```
ng version
```

You installed angular cli globally (-g in the command). This means that you can type `ng version` into your command prompt. It may be more precise to do this when your command prompt is *not* within a npm controlled directory (you *should* type this in within directory you typed `ng new myapp`).

**A note to those who got here from Google:** `ng version` will let you know which (coarse) version of Angular is referenced by the current directory. 
e.g. This directory appears to have angular 4.x (~4.3.0) installed.

```
@angular/cli: 1.2.1
node: 8.11.1
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 4.3.0
@angular/compiler: 4.3.0
@angular/core: 4.3.0
@angular/forms: 4.3.0
@angular/http: 4.3.0
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.0
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.0
@angular/router: 4.3.0
@angular/cli: 1.2.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.0
```

If you are not within a directory which has a packages.config, then you will get `Angular: ...`.

Comment: ng version will not provide you angular version. you need to check package.json to know the angular version

Comment: @SureshKamrushi i can second this, it displayed everything **except** the version

Comment: `ng version` does provide de Angular version **if** you are on the project folder.

Comment: If you are in the project folder ng version will provide the version of angular the project is using along with other information like Angular cli version, node version, TypeScript version, webpack version, rxjs version etc.

Comment: If you do not have the Angular command-line tool installed globally, you can use `npx ng version` to instruct Node(/npm) to execute the project's version of `ng`. This might limit some of the confusion about whether you are in the project directory as well. `npx` is available with node 5.2.0 and above.

Answer (score 60):

### For Angular 1 or 2 (but not for Angular 4+):

You can also open the **console** and go to the element tab on the developer tools of whatever browser you use.

***Or***

Type angular.version to access the Javascript object that holds angular version.

### For Angular 4+ There is are the number of ways as listed below :

Write below code in the command prompt/or in the terminal in the VS Code. (up to 3)

> 1. ng version or ng --version (Find the image for the reference)
> 2. ng v
> 3. ng -v

In the terminal you can find the angular version as shown in the attached image :
[image]

> 4. You can also open the **console** and go to the element tab on the developer tools of whatever browser you use. As displayed in the below image :

[image]

> 5. Find the package.json file, You will find all the installed dependencies and their version.

Answer (score 15):

You should check package.json file in the project. There you will see all packages installed and versions of those packages.

Answer (score 13):

In Command line we can check our installed ng version.

```
ng -v OR ng --version OR ng version
```

This will give you like this :

```
 _                      _                 ____ _     ___

   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/

Angular CLI: 1.6.5
Node: 8.0.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 
...
```

Comment: @viki, is this angular 5
can you tell me how do we identify which is angular 4,3,5

Comment: @vinod. Angular CLI: > 1.3 is consider as Anguar 5. Below this is Angular 4.

Comment: can you explain to me why it says `Angular: `..... shouldn't it display the version there?

Comment: It's 2020 & Angular 9 is here! And I still se ... as my Angular version. Why is it showing like that?

Answer (score 11):

`ng v`

Simply run the command above in terminal.

Answer (score 9):

> There are many way, you check angular version Just pent the comand
>   prompt(for windows) and type

```
1. ng version
2. ng v
3. ng -v
```

[image: check the angular version using comand line]

```
4. You can pakage.json file
```

[image: check the angular version on pakage.json file]

```
5.You can check in browser by presing F12 then goto elements tab
```

[image: check the angular version on your browser]

Full understanding of subversion about(x.x.x) please see angular documentation [angularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/object/angular.version) and [angular 2+](https://angular.io/api/core/Version)

Answer (score 8):

Use one of these commands in the terminal (with the Angular CLI installed already):

```
$ ng --version
```

or

```
$ ng v
```

But note that depending on the folder you are in, you will get different results.

If you are NOT in an angular project folder, then will see a result like this with no clearly stated `Angular: version` line, unless referring to the `angular core` in the package block (as the *version*) :)

```
Angular CLI: 11.0.4
Node: 14.15.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...
Ivy Workspace:

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1100.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         11.0.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   11.0.4 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          11.0.4 (cli-only)
@schematics/update           0.1100.4 (cli-only)
```

And if you run the command IN an angular project folder, you will see a similar result like this with the `Angular: 8.2.14` clearly stated (plus some dots).

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.29
Node: 14.15.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... core

Package                             Version
-------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect           0.803.29
@angular-devkit/core                8.3.29
@angular-devkit/schematics          8.3.29
@angular/cli                        8.3.29
@angular/common                     2.4.10
@angular/compiler                   2.4.10
@angular/compiler-cli               2.4.10
@angular/forms                      2.4.10
@angular/http                       2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser           2.4.10
@angular/router                     3.4.10
...
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer given by D. Squire was accurate, but possibly only a tad vague.  If you change directories to a project and then type ng --version, it will display the angular version in the project.  If done from a default directory (not within a project), you will only get the Angular CLI version, which is probably not what you are looking for and will give the output shown by Vik2696.

```
$ cd my-project
$ ng --version   // done within project directory

Angular CLI: 1.6.8
Node: 8.9.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.29
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.52
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.8
@schematics/angular: 0.1.17
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.10.0
```

Answer (score 3):

After installing **Angular CLI** globally you can ***run*** this ***command*** in **any directory** to get all the details.

```
ng version
```

To install **Angular CLI** globally using **NPM** *(Node Package Manager)*

```
npm install - g @angular/CLI
```

I have tried in *VS Code* terminal in ***bash*** and here it looks-->

[image: How to check Angular Version]

Answer (score 2):

Angular CLI ng v does output few more thing than just the version.

If you only want the version from it the you can add pipe grep and filter for angular like:

```
ng v | grep 'Angular:'
```

OUTPUT:

```
Angular: #.#.# <-- VERSION
```

For this, I have an alias which is

```
alias ngv='ng v | grep 'Angular:''
```

Then just use **ngv**

Answer (score 2):

run ng version

then simply check the version of angular core package.

```
@angular/cli: 1.2.6
node: 8.11.1
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.3.2
@angular/common: 4.3.2
@angular/compiler: 4.3.2
**@angular/core: 4.3.2**
@angular/forms: 4.3.2
```

Answer (score 2):

In the terminal type in either `ng -v` or `ng --version`.

Answer (score 1):

1. ng v
2. ng --v

you shall see something like the following:

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.8
Node: 10.15.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.10
... animations, common, compiler, core, forms, http
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
```

Angular version is in line 4 above

Answer (score 1):

ng --version command returns the details of the version of Angular CLI installed

### Updated:

You can use ng version to check the version of Angular CLI installed

Answer (score 0):

From angular 7 on-wards the following two commands are working

```
ng --version 
ng version
```

Answer (score 0):

First install the Angular/cli globally in machine.
to install the angular/cli run the command **npm install -g @angular/cli**

Above Angular7 , use these two commands [image]to know the version of Angular/Cli
1. **ng --version,**
2.**ng version**

Answer (score 0):

check the  Command Prompt

ng --version OR ng version OR ng -v

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cents, in Angular 9 (didn't check older versions) you can find angular version in root div attributes and this is how I show current version in app-root component (extract and save it in my Global's for use in other components:

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
....
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: `<div>
    <h1>TestApp: .NetCore3.1 + PostgreSql 12 + Angular {{ngVersion}}</h1>
</div>
....
 `
})
export class AppComponent {
  ngVersion: string;
  constructor(private router: Router, private el: ElementRef) {
    ....    
    //read ng-verion and save it in Global's
    Global.ngVersion = this.el.nativeElement.getAttribute("ng-version");
    this.ngVersion = Global.ngVersion.substring(0, 1);
    ....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get just the Angular CLI version number with Powershell on Windows try:

`ng v | Select-String -Pattern 'Angular CLI'`

Example output: `Angular CLI: 9.1.9`

Answer (score 0):

In angular you can write every command in short form or full form.
so to check angular version open CMD or command prompt and just write ng version or ng v

where ng stands for angular and v stands for version.

Answer (score -1):

```
ng --version
```

you can watch this vidio to install the latest angular version.
https://youtu.be/zqHqMAWqpD8