# Downgrade angular version and not just angular cli

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular9

I have downgraded angular cli version and when I run the command `ng serve`, the following message is displayed

`ERROR : This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions 0.0.0 || ^8.0.0-beta || >=8.0.0 <9.0.0 but Angular version 9.0.7 was found instead`.

I looked at https://update.angular.io to find instructions on how to update Angular, but I do not want to update the angular CLI version, I want to downgrade the angular version from 9.0.7 to 8.0.0. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

First of all check your installed angular version through this command

```
ng --version
```

If you are already on desired version then you just have to update `@angular/cli` version in your project `package.json` file to make it compatible .
Sometimes when we are using project developed on other machine causes this sort of issue

If  `ng --version` shows that you are not on desired version then follow these steps to downgrade

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@8.0.0  // In your case 8.0.0
```

For complete guide check **ReadMe** part of [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli) github repository.

Same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363530/how-to-downgrade-angular-cli-version)

Comment: When i run the commands for installing cli , it does not effect or downgrade angular version. How can i downgrade the angular version?

Comment: On which version are you currently ?

Comment: Angular CLI: 8.2.2
Node: 12.13.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 9.0.7 => I want this to be 8.2.2 as well

Comment: Did you globally run above commands ? Downgrading is basically uninstalling existing version and then install it again by mentioning required version.

Comment: Yeah I did. It only downgrades the cli and not angular

Comment: what is angular version in your `package.json` of project ?

Comment: [Angular Cli vs Angular Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46332383/how-to-check-the-angular-version) . Check this it would make easier for you to identify your peak problem. You seem confused