# Creating new angular project using angular cli - @angular/cli and @angular/core show different versions in package.json

Tags: angular, angular-cli, npm-install

Angular beginner here. Currently held assumption - when creating a new angular project, versions of packages in package.json should match those in npmjs website.

`npm list -g` shows the following

```
/usr/local/lib
├── @angular/cli@14.0.5
├── corepack@0.10.0
└── npm@8.13.2
```

Upon creating a new angular app using `ng new demo`, inside package.json, @angular/cli version is 14.0.5 - but @angular/core version is 14.0.0

package.json

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  }
}
```

`ng update @angular/core` shows `Package '@angular/core' is already up to date.`
But `npm install @angular/core` bumps the version to 14.0.5 in package.json file.

Why doesn't the latest cli install latest `@angular/<other packages>`?

Comment: As per answers to [Vinicius Brasil's question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46332383/19530650), `ng version` outside an angular project shows version of `@angular/cli`. But `ng version` inside an angular project will also show versions of `@angular/core` & other `@angular/<other_packages>`  too.

So package.json will show the semantic versions with ~ & ^.
To know exact version installed, I should use `ng version` inside angular project. (Which in this case is showing 14.0.5 for all `@angular/<other_packages>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are doing slightly different things though the outcome is similar. Basically `ng update` may also check for schematics to decide if based on compatibility, it would actually bump the version - or not. `npm i` will just do it, no checks. `ng` is done with Angular CLI and `npm` with npm CLI so their different in their behavior because they are different things.
https://angular.io/guide/schematics#update-schematics

If you were on `"@angular/core": "13.0.0"` while everything else was at 14 and did `ng update` most likely you will be bumped to 14 with the core. But in your case, it was best decided to stay on `14.0.0` and ignore the minor version `14.0.5`.

Upgrading Angular stuff with `ng update` is a good idea, because of schematics. Other 3rd party packages probably don't have schematics so well have to make do with `npm i`.